# Vim: Convert backticks to $() notation in shell script

Tags: text-processing, vim

Suppose I have some statements in a shell (bash) script like

```
var=`cat file.txt`
echo "Date is: `date`"
```

I want to convert the backtick notation into `$()` notation like:

```
var=$(cat file.txt)
echo "Date is: $(date)"
```

How can I do this in Vim with search/replacement, for the entire file?

Motivation: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
:% s/`\([^`]*\)`/$(\1)/gc
```

`g` makes it global (for all entries in line), `c` makes `vim` to ask user about each replace.

But it won't work with nested backticks and multi-line code. Only for pairs backticks in line.

You can also quit from `vim` and use `sed` for this:

```
sed -n -i.backup 'N; ${s/`\([^`]*\)`/$(\1)/g; p; q}; b' filename
```

It will work with multi-line backtrics, but without nested.

Comment: Add a `c` after the `g` to manually confirm each substitution. I would also add double quotes around each `$(...)` but that might make things messy if you have backticks inside double quotes already. May be better to do that afterwards.

Comment: `c` modifier can be useful, yes. But i don't think it is really good idea to automatically wrap it into double quotes.

Comment: Why would you wrap a statement like `var=$(date)` into doublequotes?